# Hibernate Search: indexBase cannot get values from config

Tags: spring, tomcat7, hibernate-search, ubuntu-server

I am using Hibernate Search in my webapp. I wanted to deploy application to Ubuntu Server with Tomcat. Yet it throws same error **independent of index location place** set in configuration file.

At beginning I set to directory in **home folder** like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/home/someuser/indexes</property>
```

Permissions of this folder were like following:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Jun 30 14:44 indexes
```

Then I tried to relative path and created folder **indexes** in **webapps** with same permissions:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">indexes</property>
```

In both case throws the same error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: 
Cannot write into index directory: .
```

I don't understand why it tries the current folder.

With regards

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search will write by default in the current directory: ".".

You are setting the correct property; the only explanation I have is that you are not setting it in the right configuration file.

Hibernate also reads JVM properties and environment variables when it doesn't find a property before resorting to the default.
I wouldn't normally recommend to set such options on the JVM command line, but it might be interesting to try this out in your case.

You can also add additional properties in a *hibernate.properties* resource file.